# type error toLowercase is not a function

Tags: javascript, string, function

I am starting out learning javascript.  I have a task where I must create a simple rock, paper scissors game against the computer.

The program will eventually prompt the human to type either rock, paper or scissors when it is their turn.  To ensure data validation the program must decapitalize any letters inputted by the human.

To do this I am trying to use the toLowercase function which can be seen in the second line of code below.

In return of my efforts i am receiving the following in the console:

TypeError: playerSelection.toLowercase is not a function

```
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {


    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowercase();
    var resultMessage = "";

    if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        resultMessage = "You Lose. Paper beats Rock"; 
    }

    else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        resultMessage = "You Win. Rock beats Scissors"; 
    }

    else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "scissors") {
        resultMessage = "You Lose. Scissors beats Paper"; 
    }

    else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        resultMessage = "You Win. Paper beats Rock"; 
    }

    else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") {
        resultMessage = "You Win. Scissors beats Paper"; 
    }

    else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "rock") {
        resultMessage = "You Win. Scissors beats Rock"; 
    }

    else {
        resultMessage = "Draw";
    }

    return resultMessage;

}

console.log(playRound("rock",compPlay));
```

Comment: Dude. it is `toLowerCase()`. Notice the camel case

Comment: `toLowerCase()` you forgot to capitalize the C.

Comment: it is [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) not the `toLowercase()`

Comment: @Pointy ups, sorry, I fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not, `toLowerCase()` is. (Case not case, more at [Camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)).

Comment: Typo question `->` Comment

Comment: Duly noted. Thanks.

Comment: Facepalm.  Thank you everyone.